# Increment column then reset to 1 every day

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

So I'm doing a ticket number system, and I need an increment column from 1 to num of items in that day, so it should reset to 1 every day.

Is there any way to do this with using only sharepoint online and microsoft flow?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have clear understanding on what DAY means, below solution can be applied. If your users are geographically distributed around world, it can get tricky, so please take with pinch of salt.

1. Write schedule based Flow - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/run-scheduled-tasks
2. This flow can Update item to a config list every night say 1AM
3. In config list there will be single item and it will be reset to one at night by this scheduled flow.
4. Now, going back to your ticket list.  Whenever new ticket is added run another MS Flow/ SPD workflow
5. This new flow will fetch current number from Config list and assign this number to new ticket.
6. In same flow, it will update config list number by an increment , so that its ready for next ticket.

You can use this in combination of dateyear and number, to keep it unique for every Ticket.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new list with Date column, single line of text field (reuse title field as Counter).
2. Set SharePoint designer workflow on item updated.
3. In workflow,set step on condition -

`if current item counter == 1 && Date == Today`

`add new item with Date = today date + 1, Counter = 1`

4 .While creating new item in your existing ticketing application, refer this newly created list (in step 1) to check date and get item ID.

5. You can keep on updating item ID to get next counter value.

Hope that helps to develop your required solution.